# pass values and return the values in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to print attributes and its values. So I have created an XSLT function.
Tried to code;

```
<xsl:template name="preserve">
    <xsl:call-template name="single"/>
    <w:r>
        <xsl:value-of select="t:get-attr-from-ele('ewd')"/>
        <w:instrText>
            <xsl:attribute name="xml:space">
                <xsl:value-of select="'preserve'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="w:ins[1]//w:instrText"/>
        </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:function name="t:get-attr-from-ele">
    <xsl:param name="attr"/>

    <xsl:attribute name="{$attr}">
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:function>
```

When I try with this I am getting following> error.

> There is no context item

How can I resolve this? I am using XSLT 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, inside of a function there is no context item so using `generate-id()` is not going to work as it requires a context item. Also if you want to have that function create an attribute node for a result it doesn't make sense to use `xsl:value-of` later to call the function as that would create text node. So basically, if inside of the function you want to use `generate-id` you need to pass a node in explicitly as a parameter (or use some global parameter or variable):

```
<xsl:function name="t:get-attr-from-ele">
    <xsl:param name="context-node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:param name="attr" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:attribute name="{$attr}">
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id($context-node)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:function>
```

Then you can use `<xsl:sequence select="t:get-attr-from-ele(., 'ewd')"/>` or `<xsl:copy-of select="t:get-attr-from-ele(., 'ewd')"/>`.